# How to check if today's month date is greater than or less than a decimal number?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with month day numbers, so 20 means the 20th of the month.

I want to know how to check if a value in this column, say 20 is more than or less than today's month day.

I would use conditional formatting to color the cell in red if that day had not passed already.

What I tried to do was set a cell with today's date:

`=TODAY()`

Then based on this calculate if the month day was less than or greater by using this:

`=DATEDIF(F2, "MD")`

I was hoping this wold return a number which I could then do a compare with but this is wrong and I am not sure if what I want to do is even possible.
I have read through the documentation and Stackoverflow but I cannot find any close examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the day of the month you need to extract exactly that.

If your date is in Cell A1 and your threshold (20) in A2 the conditional formatting formula to check if the date has not passed yet would then go:

```
=DAY(A1) < A2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer this worked. I want to use it in conditional logic but using a range does not seem to work =DAY(F2) >20 & DAY(F2) <23

Comment: If you are applying this formatting to a range consider that it works as if you were dragging the formula from the top left of the range. Maybe you need to lock the cell using `$F$2`